# Resizing Logical Group and Physical Volumes to use free space

Tags: partitioning, lvm, resize, fdisk, boot-partition

I recently moved the unencrypted /boot from /dev/sda1 into the root of my encrypted LVM. Afterwards I deleted the /dev/sda1 and ended up with roughly 513MB of free space that I would like to reclaim. One way to do this is create a new partition with fdisk, add a new pv and assign it in the Group. Nevertheless I wonder if it is possible to resize the /dev/sda2 instead. Is this possible?

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x97d1dae4

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda2       1001470 937701375 936699906 446.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 937701375 936699904 446.7G 83 Linux
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

**It's VERY dangerous and you might risk losing your data and/or making your system unbootable.**

Still it worked for me without problems. Here is what I did:

- I boot with live CD, opened gparted and allocated all remaining free disk to /dev/sda2. Then I also resized /dev/sda5 (this is the dangerous bit).
- Since I had to move the partition to the left, I risked messing up my /boot. In my case it did not but if you face problems run Boot-Repair.
- Allocate the remaining disk to the volume of your choice. In my case I did something like: `pvresize /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt; lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/root; resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/root`